# Construction of a discrete random variable uniformly choosing random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(R_{n,k})_{n \in \mathbb{N}, k \le n}$ a sequence of iid discrete random variables.

I think that Kolmogorov proved such variables exist in a probability space.
I want to construct a sequence of variables $(Q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $Q_n$ is a random variable among $R_{n_1}, \dots, R_{n,n}$.
Is it possible ?
How can I justify its existence ?
I already thought that $Q_n$ could be of the form $Q_n=R_{n,N_n}$ where $N_n$ is a random variable choosing uniformly a number in $[\![1;n]\!] $ but I don't know if $N_n$ exists in the same probability space.
Can I define all these variables so that they are all independent ?

Comment: I think in general you must enlarge the probability space. You need e.g. an independent continuous uniform variable living alongside the $R_{n,k}$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space where $(R_{n,k})_{n\in\Bbb N,k\le n}$ exists.

Consider also the canonical space $([0,1),\mathcal B[0,1),\text{Leb})$, where $U\colon[0,1)\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto U(x):=x$ represents a uniform variable.

Now construct the product space $\Omega':=\Omega\times[0,1)$, $\mathcal A':=\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B[0,1)$, and $\mathbb Q:=\mathbb P\otimes\text{Leb}$. We can still see $U$ and the $R_{n,k}$'s as random variables defined on $(\Omega',\mathcal A',\mathbb Q)$ via
$R_{n,k}(\omega,x):=R_{n,k}(\omega)$ and $U(\omega,x):=U(x)$. By construction $(R_{n,k})_{n\in\Bbb N,k\le n}$ and $U$ are further independent.

The random variable $Q_n(\omega,x):=R_{n,\lceil nx\rceil}(\omega)$ answers your question.

Comment: Thank you ! And $Q_n$ is still a discrete random variable !